# How to deploy a Jasper Report in Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, jasper-reports

I'm a newbie to Jasper Reports.

I'm currently developing a toy application using Glassfish 3.1 with Netbeans 7. I'm able to create a Jasper Report in Netbeans and test it (in Netbeans), ,but when I'm trying to deploy the application with the report it shows errors in the log when starting the application and when try to run the Jasper Report (created dynamically by a Servlet) it gives compilation error.

I get the information for the report directly from a JavaBean Datasource (not from a Database). The report is PESMModelReport.jsrxml I don't know what can be wrong.

This the log when I start Glassfish with the Jasper report:

```
SEVERE: Exception while visiting SimModSystem-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT_war/WEB-INF/classes/com/librethinking/simmodsys/jasper/PESMModelReport.class of size 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:362)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: Exception while visiting SimModSystem-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT_war/WEB-INF/classes/com/librethinking/simmodsys/jasper/ModelReport.class of size 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:362)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: Exception while visiting com/librethinking/simmodsys/jasper/PESMModelReport.class of size 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:362)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.parse(DirectoryArchive.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.parse(DirectoryArchive.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.parse(DirectoryArchive.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.parse(DirectoryArchive.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.parse(DirectoryArchive.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.onSelectedEntries(DirectoryArchive.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: Exception while visiting com/librethinking/simmodsys/jasper/ModelReport.class of size 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:362)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.parse(DirectoryArchive.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.parse(DirectoryArchive.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.parse(DirectoryArchive.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.parse(DirectoryArchive.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.parse(DirectoryArchive.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.util.DirectoryArchive.onSelectedEntries(DirectoryArchive.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

and this is the log when I try to execute the report:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilationFailedException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:157)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getCompiler(JasperCompileManager.java:730)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:240)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:490)
    at com.librethinking.simmodsys.web.ModelsController.prepareReport(ModelsController.java:298)
    at com.librethinking.simmodsys.web.ModelsController.showReport(ModelsController.java:313)
    at com.librethinking.simmodsys.web.ModelsController.processRequest(ModelsController.java:93)
    at com.librethinking.simmodsys.web.ModelsController.doGet(ModelsController.java:145)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationFailedException
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1519)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1369)
    ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jasper tries to find the Groovy libraries in classpath. It seems that by default the expression language for a newly created Jasper report is Groovy. You should find in "Report properties" a section called "Language". Choose it to be Java then recompile and redeploy your report.

I've managed to attach a screenshot from my iReport.

[image: Here is a screenshot from iReport]